# line access after importing a file in python

Tags: python, for-loop, file-access

I am new to python, and I have loaded two files containing gene expression counts. Now, I want to check if the expression count of each gene in the sample set is similar to its representative in the reference set. For this, I am using a for loop. I need the syntax for the for loop, where I can look for specific lines in the sample and reference file.

For example, my file look like this:

```
gene_name    expression count

actin              2.3

tubulin           -0.08
```

Please give me the syntax for the for loop, which would help me access tubulin from the reference file and then I can check if sample value for tubulin is the same as in the reference using an if statement.

This is what I am currently using:

```
sample = open("s1_gene_list.txt","r") 
ref = open("ref_gene_list.txt","r") 
my_list=[x for x in range(ref.tubulin-5,ref.tubulin+5,1)]
```

Comment: stick to Excel match and index if you could not spare the cost to give trials.

Comment: What code do you have at the moment?

Comment: mwil.e, this is what I'm currently using. The list defines ref.tubulin, that is where I want to check the count of reference tubulin, give it a flexible range of -5 to +5 and look for sample tubulin within this range.      `sample = open("s1_gene_list.txt","r")`                                                       `ref = open("ref_gene_list.txt","r")`                                                                        `my_list=[x for x in range(ref.tubulin-5,ref.tubulin+5,1)]`                                         Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use nested loops one for reading the elements in the list and other for checking other lists in the same sample files.

Comment: Could you please give me a syntax for that?